# ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION UnhandledPromiseRejection when awaited inside an array of promise Objects

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to understand async await with promises and for..of loop. I have a function which generates promise by resolving if an even number is passed to it and by rejecting if odd number is passed to it. Inside an async function I am tying to await but getting UnhandledPromiseRejection even though I am catching the error.
My question is what points i am missing. Why I am getting UnhandledPromiseRejection and how to handle it. I need conceptual information

```js
function genPromise(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (value % 2) {
            resolve(`The value ${value} is odd`);
        } else {
            reject(`The value ${value} is even`);
        }
    })
}

(async function () {

    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let y = x.map(d => genPromise(d))
    try {
        for await (let k of y) {
            console.log(k);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for await(` is only intended for use with async iterables. You do not have an async iterable - only a normal iterable, in which case it's equivalent to `for..of`:

```
for (const k of y) {
  console.log(k);
}
```

The `k` promise is not being caught, hence the rejection.

Await `k` inside the loop, without `for await`:

```js
function genPromise(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (value % 2) {
            resolve(`The value ${value} is odd`);
        } else {
            reject(`The value ${value} is even`);
        }
    })
}

(async function () {

    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let y = x.map(d => genPromise(d))
    try {
        for (const k of y) {
            console.log(await k);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error', err)
    }
})();
```

If you wanted to make an async iterable from the array of numbers, then you'd do something like:

```js
function* genPromise(arr) {
    for (const value of arr) {
        yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (value % 2) {
                resolve(`The value ${value} is odd`);
            } else {
                reject(`The value ${value} is even`);
            }
        });
    }
}

(async function () {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    try {
        for await (const k of genPromise(arr)) {
            console.log(k);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error', err)
    }
})();
```

Comment: Node.js is still thowing me the

Comment: The `reject` is causing the Promise to reject, but the error is being caught by the `catch` block as desired.

Comment: And the loop stops its not processing the next promises. Is this the desired behaviour. what if i want it to continue

Comment: If you want it to continue, catch inside the loop instead of outside.